# twitter-bootstrap-rails nav_bar helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

hy i'm trying to use [this gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) to generate a responsive nar_bar.
it work fine for me:

```
<%= nav_bar fixed: :top , brand: "Some_brand" , :responsive => true do %>

  <%= menu_group pull: :right do %>
      <%= drop_down "Services" do %>
          <%= menu_item "a",a_path %>
          <%= menu_item "b",b_path %>
          <%= drop_down_divider %>
          <%= menu_item "c",c_path %>
      <% end %>
      <%= menu_item "About",about_path %>
      <%= menu_item "Portfolio",portfolio_path %>
  <% end %>
```

now i want to use a logo.jpg image in brand instead "Some brand". Something like this:

```
      <%= nav_bar fixed: :top , brand: :image_tag('logo.jpg') , :responsive => true do %>
```

i don't know if the helper method work whit image_tag. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work or not, but the code you showed definitely has an issue.  Including the `:` before `image_tag` is telling Rails that `image_tag` is a symbol and not a method.  You might try removing the extra colon.

```
<%= nav_bar fixed: :top , brand: image_tag('logo.jpg') , :responsive => true do %>
```

Comment: thanks, i have used your solution but doesn't works. Using your syntax  the options aren't in hash form.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  Here on StackOverflow when you get an answer that solves your problem you should "accept" the answer by clicking on the green check mark that shows up next to the answer when you hover over it.